# Sticky Header on Fullcalendar scheduler

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am getting mad with trying to get sticky header with full calendar scheduler.
I tried

```
height: "parent"
```

I saw a lot of posts but none of them worked.

but then there are 2 scrollbars (one for the main window and one for the calendar).

Is there a solution for having sticky header?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Finally it worked with something like

```
.fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar {
    position: sticky;
    top: 70px;
    z-index: 10;
    background: white
}

.fc-head-container.fc-widget-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 108px;
    z-index: 10;
    background: white;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: hi, is it possible to sticky also the timeline?

Answer (score 0):

I did't get the point about the full calender scheduler, If you want header element should be stickyed one, apply the below css for your header.

```
 position: fixed; top: 0; left:0; width: 100%;
```

try and let me know.

Comment: Why not `position: sticky;`? [MDN - Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: thanks but it doesn t work. Could you show me on https://jsfiddle.net/u71jbdew/25/ ?? Trying to make it work from https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.4/demos/vertical-resource-view.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, this works for me:

```css
    .fc-timeline .fc-body .fc-scroller{
       height: 400px  !important;
    }
```